# Jquery popup window and persisting data on ActionLink click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a question regarding data persistence on ActionLink click.
I have a page and the user enters some information in the input fields. One of the fields uses jquery autocomplete and if the value they are looking for does not exist, then they can click the action link to create it. A jquery popup window opens. On submit the user is returned to the main view. The problem is that the data previously entered does not exist.
My question is how I can achieve this and at the same time the popup window to appear. I tried using Ajax.ActionLink but the partial view does not appear as popup window.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "On submit the user is returned to the main view" here are you doing a page load ? Did you try post your data using ajax and closing the popup window ?

Comment: I store the data from the popup window in the database in a controller action and this action then redirects me again to the main form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening the popup window, you can send the data you collected from the popup to controller via [`AJAX` post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) with JavaScript.

Then after saving to the database controller can return the created entity or relevant fields as a JsonResult and you can use those data to set the autocomplete field value.

After that you can close the popup using JavaScript and previously entered data in the parent window will not lost since you are not redirecting.

Thanks!